# Eclipse lost line numbers

Tags: macos, eclipse, text-editors, perl

My eclipse no longer shows line numbers, its configured to do and it did before

(I believe it became like this after I moved its application folder, mac osx)

The settings read that it's supposed to show line numbers but the right click menu on the left strip where line nums are displayed shows that "Show Line Numbers" is not ticked, clicking it changes nothing.

Any conf files or settings I must go through to force line numbers again?

I think since this is happening only for perl .cgi files, Eclipse considers them binary and doesn't work the same way. How to overwrite that? It's perfectly fine in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you haven't moved your workspace folder, this is weird. However, if you have set up your workspace inside the application directory, than it looks obvious to me again, because Eclipse may not find it's (moved) settings.

Go to your workspace folder. You should find a `.metadata` directory. In here search for `.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`.

To enable line numbers look for a line like

```
lineNumberRuler=true
```

Try adding it if it doesn't exist.

If your workspace folder *is* inside your application folder you should think of moving it to a different place, e.g. `Documents` in your home folder - I'm also on a mac and have a `~/Projects` for those things. Inside here I have `workspace`for my Eclipse work.
After moving you have to enter the path on first start of eclipse.

Also make sure it's writable.

Comment: I think it finds them in that config file I saw the spiteful undo buffer setting at 9000 (which Mac ignores of course) I see this setting in the preferences window in eclipse itself. The line numbers line is in the config.

Comment: But yes I have moved my folder and it still doesnt show them. It shows line numbers for other source files, CSS html you name it just not CGI. (perl) Is there a setting to show line numbers for binary files, I think eclipse considers them binary.

Comment: Ah, for perl... are you using EPIC?

Comment: Oh well.. there is no additional setting regarding epic. Perl should text file not binary. However, you may check which editor is being used when you open a cgi file. You can add an additional file extension so that cgi files are opened with your (perl?) editor plugin.

Comment: Yeah I did that after those edits i made to my answer but didn't fix the issue. Yes, Perl EPIC

Comment: I found deep buried line number setting now it worked, schoolboy error here... thanks guys.

Comment: Just for completion: which settings have you found where?

Comment: In Preferences: Perl EPIC > Editor I didnt see it before because I was using the filter on top writing "editors" plural, the Perl one simply doesn't show up..

Comment: Where is the deep buried line number setting?